# How to fix the problem with duplicates when synchronizing Google tables and Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am using a simple script to sync google tables and google calendar, it works great. But when adding a new event, each time a duplicate of the previous ones is added, how can this problem be eliminated? Thank you.

My script

```
function scheduleShifts() {
  const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const calendarId = spreadsheet.getRange("E1").getValue();
  const eventCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  const signups = spreadsheet.getRange("B2:D15").getValues();
  for (let x = 0; x < signups.length; x++) {
    const shift = signups[x];
    const name = shift[0];
    const startTime = shift[1];
    const endTime = shift[2];
    eventCal.createEvent(name, startTime, endTime);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could take your minimum starttime and your maximum endtime and search for event titles in that range and they check to see if your new name is in that last with either indexOf() or includes();

Comment: The best solution solution for you depends on how you use this spreadsheet. Could you give us an explanation on how you use it? Why is the range always `B2:D15`? (Are you reusing the spreadsheet?)

Comment: @Martí I can't say that I'm using the table for its intended purpose. The true purpose of the table is to get the data form "name" "email" "start of vacation" "end of vacation" from Google and then synchronize them with the Google calendar (using the script I indicated above) The only problem is that I want to implement updates data in the calendar when changing in the table, but so that old events are not duplicated)

Comment: @Cooper  Thank you. I will try to implement it when I learn a little more information :D

Comment: @ArtemLisovets If you've figured out a way to get this working correctly, I'd love to see your solution if you're willing to share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest way is to add a column where you save the event IDs of each row. When a row is modified, you can check if the event ID is set. If it is, you can edit the already-existing event; if it's not, you create a new one.

I leave some reference of the function you'll probably have to use. Also, let us know if there something that's not clear or that need further explanation :)

### References

- [CalendarApp.getEventById(iCalId) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventbyidicalid)
- [CalendarEvent.getId() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getid)
- [Range.setValue(value) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)